# Alerts will come if SAS token Expiry

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Need get alerts, if SAS token Expiry.Thing is In production We can't create SAS token  Every 30days, So please automatically It will generate new access token or at least we need to get alerts, any one help me  on that

Comment: How are these SAS Tokens generated and consumed?

Comment: Please share more details on where you want to use the sas token and how they are used

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the possibility to revoke access than i would use Access keys instead. If this is an option for you?